# Google Map API v3 - map working in FF, Chrome but not IE 9

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-9

I seem to be having the opposite issue of some of the other issues I've seen posted. I've been playing with the GM API v3 and it's working just fine in FF (v16) and Chrome (v23), but it will not display in IE(9).

I'm still trying to learn Javascript, so I'm assuming that is where the issue is, but I've pretty much used the example scripts provided by Google.  I also know that FF is more forgiving browser, but I've validated my HTML code and it seems pretty clean. After messing with this the past few days, I'm officially stumped and sure could use the help of someone much smarter than me (which shouldn't be too hard!).

Here's the url: http://www.conleym.com/map/ced/directions.html

if anyone is willing to take a look, I'd sure appreciate it!

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` probably has something to do with it. (Edit:  It does, the map shows right up when the document mode is IE9 standards)

Comment: Good Lord - how embarrassing!  I've been so focused on thinking it was the javascript I didn't even bother to look at that.  Thanks!